Are there any prime numbers $\geq 5$ which are not a factor of some $n!-1,\ $ where $n\geq 2$?
For each $n\in\mathbb{N},$ let $S_n$ be the set of prime factors of $n! + 1$. By Wilson's theorem, we have $\ p\mid (p-1)!+1\ $ for every prime $p.$ Therefore, $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n \supset \bigcup_{n \text{ is prime }} S_{n-1} = \mathbb{P},\ $ the set of primes. Trivially, this implies that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n = \mathbb{P}.$
A natural follow-up question is:

For each $n\in\mathbb{N},$ let $T_n$ be the set of prime factors of
$n! - 1.\ $ Is $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=2}^{\infty} T_n = \mathbb{P}\setminus\{2,3\} ?$

Stated alternatively, does there exist a prime $p\geq 5$ such that $p$ does not divide $n!-1$ for all integers $n$? I found no counter-examples up to and including $p=23,$ in particular, $19\mid 17! -1,$ and $23\mid 21! -1$ found using this and this. I'm not sure if Wilson's theorem can be used for this problem.
Related.
Maybe this is an open problem?

$$(p-2)!\equiv -(p-1)(p-2)!=-(p-1)!\equiv 1\pmod p.$$

FYI, as you stated with $19$ and $23$, we have by Wilson's theorem that $(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ which leads to $(p-2)!(p-1)\equiv -1\pmod{p};\to;(p-2)!\equiv 1\pmod{p};\to;p\mid (p-2)!-1$. Thus, there are no such primes $p \ge 5$.

Note that, using an Approach0 search, there are $2$ somewhat related questions of Using Wilson's Theorem and Concerning Wilsons Theorem.

I checked with Maple all primes below 1000, all are "good". Not surprisingly it's $(p-2)!+1$...

$p$ divides $a:=(p-2)!-1$ if and only if $p$ divides $(p-1)a$. But
$$
(p-1)a=(p-1)!-p+1=[(p-1)!+1] -p
$$
and the expression in $[]$ is divisible by $p$ by Wilson's theorem.
